# I have an image metadata database. For simplicity's sake, there are three tables: image, imageperson, and person

Tags: sql, subquery, metadata

I have an image metadata database.  For simplicity's sake, there are three tables:

- image (metadata for the images),
- imageperson (which persons appear in which images)
- person (metadata for the persons)

I think it's clear there is a many-to-many relationship between image and person, and that imageperson is the relation table between them.

The following query

```
SELECT image.id
FROM image, imageperson, person
WHERE image.id = imageperson.id
AND imageperson.id = person.id
AND person.id = 5;
```

returns all the images for a particular person.

Question: I want to find the images that contain two particular persons that I specify in the query, for example, 5 and 6.  It's ok if there are other people in the image and those are returned as part of the results.

I can't figure it out and I think the answer involves subqueries, but I can't get my head around the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the database you're using, you can accomplish this a couple of ways.  Here's one option using `COUNT` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM image i
  JOIN imageperson ip ON i.id = ip.imageid
  JOIN person p ON ip.personid = p.id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.id IN (5,6) THEN 1 END) = 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc591/1)

Also please note, I've updated your original query to use the more standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: For the record, I am using SQLite and your answer works.  Is is possible to replace the case statement with another SQL statement?  If so, would then I have some sort of subquery?  If so, which type?  I ask because I want to understand your answer better.

Comment: `SELECT image.id
FROM image, imageperson, person
WHERE image.id = imageperson.id
AND imageperson.id = person.id
AND person.id = 5

UNION

SELECT image.id
FROM image, imageperson, person
WHERE image.id = imageperson.id
AND imageperson.id = person.id
AND person.id = 6;`

works as well.  I did some tests and the union statement is faster.